# Groovy on Jenkins: Plot plugin

Tags: jenkins, plot, groovy, jenkins-plugins

I currently have a Groovy script running on Jenkins that generates XML report files. The goal is to have the data presented to the user in plots.

So far I've been using the plot plugin post-build option on Jenkins to do this but would like to automate it. I've been looking for information on how to do this with my Groovy script but can't find anything.

A short sample of the XML would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <xmllog>
  <asicbuilduser> 44.5 </asicbuilduser>
 </xmllog>
```

The `XPath Expression` is `xmllog/*` and the `XPath Result type` is `Nodeset`

Comment: and what do you want to plot according to the value `44.5` ?

Comment: just a dotted plot, where `44.5` will be the `Y` value. In the file there was more data, I just placed this snippet to give a sense of how the `xml` was constructed. The goal is for each instance of `asicbuilduser` to have a dot where the associated value is plotted in the `Y` axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the way to go for using plots with Groovy code in Jenkins is with a Pipeline project.